# For an analytic function $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$, if $f(0) = \alpha$ and $f'(0) = 0$, then prove an inequality of $|f(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is an old qualifying exam question.  The unit disk $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1\}$ is denoted by $\mathbb{D}$.

> For an analytic function $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$, if $f(0) = \alpha$ and $f'(0) = 0$, then for $|z| \le \sqrt{|\alpha|}$, $$|f(z)| \ge \frac{|\alpha| - |z|^2}{1 + |\alpha||z|^2}$$

My hunch is to use the Cauchy integral formula -- for $C$ the counter-clockwise closed circular curve centered at 0 of radius $\sqrt{|\alpha|}$ and fixed $w$ inside $C$,
$$ f(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z - w} dz$$
which gives us 
$$f(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z} dz = \alpha \qquad \text{ and } \quad f'(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z^2} dz = 0$$
From here, I'm not seeing anything immediate.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$g(z) = \frac{f(z)-\alpha}{1- \overline \alpha f(z)}$$
maps $\Bbb D$ into itself, with $g(0) = g'(0) = 0$.

Applying the Schwarz Lemma twice (to $g(z)$ and $g(z)/z$) it follows that
$$
 \left\vert \frac{f(z)-\alpha}{1- \overline \alpha f(z)} \right \vert
 \le |z|^2 \, .
$$
Therefore
$$
 |\alpha| - |f(z)| \le |z|^2 ( 1 + |\alpha| |f(z)|) \, ,
$$
from which the desired conclusion follows.